# Persistent connection between Android - PHP - Mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli, android-asynctask

Hi all I have a question about PHP connection and Android. 
I have got some PHP files, in everyone of this file I make a call for connect to the database

```
new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

and after, I will do a query to extract data from DB and return a JSON to Android into an AsyncTask. I have seen that make everytime a call to

```
new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

was very slow.

My question is, is there a way for speed up connection to DB or save the connection for the first time, into Android and after pass as parameter to PHP files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless your $servername is too far away from the server where PHP runs, ther should be no noticeable timeout. Can you please define a "very slow" thing in more certain numbers? And also provide an evidence that it's indeed `new mysqli` part takes all the time?

Answer (score 0):

For the servername you can use "p:servername" for example:

```
new mysqli("p:db.test.com", "user", "pass", "db");
```

Apache will then create a persistent connection that gets reused.

If you want to use it in the same request you can always save it in a variable like this:

```
$db = new mysqli("db.test.com", "user", "pass", "db");
```

and call your functions to the `$db` variable

Read throught this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php for further information